# No Max() applicable: Sequence contains no elements

Tags: c#

I have a list `list` with items in it like this

```
ElementA: Number=1, Version=1
ElementB: Number=1, Version=2 
ElementC: Number=1, Version=3 <-
ElementD: Number=2, Version=1
ElementE: Number=2, Version=2 <-
ElementF: Number=3, Version=1 <-
```

and I want to select all items which have the highest `Version` in a group with items of same `Number`. (See the arrows above.)

I would like to use a query for this so I've tried this:

```
var result = from a in list where a.Version >=
            (from b in list where b.Number == a.Number && b != a select b.Version).Max() select a;
```

This is working fine, if every group of items with the same `Number` consists of at least 2 elements, but otherwise it throws an InvalidOperationException if the inner query contains no elements.

How can I rewrite the query to get what I want? I would be grateful for every hint. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this should do the trick, but without copying your data myself I cannot test it:

```
var result = 
     list.GroupBy(x => x.Number)
         .Select(gr => 
                    gr.OrderByDescending(x => x.Version)
                      .First());
```

as Henrik noticed this will only get you one item - I didn't see the reason to get more because the items seemd only to consist of the two fields, but this is easily handeled - just add another group for the version:

```
var result = 
     list.GroupBy(x => x.Number)
         .Select(gr =>
                    gr.GroupBy(x => x.Version)
                      .OrderByDescending(gr2 => gr2.Key)
                      .Select(gr => gr.ToArray()));
```

This should result in a enumeration of Arrays with the largest versions - but again I cannot test so there might be syntax or semantic errors but the indent should be clear and errors easy to remove.

Comment: Notice the plural in the question: "I want to select all items which have the highest Version in a group". This solution only selects one item in each group.

Comment: Henrik: right, Michael seems to be fine but I will add another one that handles this problem

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you want to group by number first, then sort by version and take the last entry:

```
var result = from entry in list
             group entry by entry.Number into g
             select g.OrderBy(x => x.Version).Last();
```

or to avoid actually ordering, if you don't mind creating a new entry:

```
var result = from entry in list
             group entry by entry.Number into g
             select new Entry { Number = g.Key,
                                Version = g.Max(x => x.Version) };
```

EDIT: Using `OrderByDescending` instead as per Carsten's approach avoids having to iterate to the last entry:

```
var result = from entry in list
             group entry by entry.Number into g
             select g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Version).First();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `&& b != a` part.

Comment: This will just return the whole list because each element would be compared to itself and `a.Version` would always be `>=` for each element.

Comment: @Michael - think again. Removing the `&& b != a` can only increase the maximum.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
var result = from e in elements
             group e by e.Number into eGroup
             select eGroup.OrderByDescending(x => x.Version).First();
```